# How do I load content when user reached end scroll using mCustomScrollbar onTotalScroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am having an error on appending content on mCustomScrollBar onToTalScroll. I want to load content when reached end scroll.

**Controller**

```
$scope.initialize = function(){
        $('#sent').mCustomScrollbar({
            scrollInertia: 350,
            callbacks:{
                onTotalScroll:function(){
                    $scope.showMore();
                }
            }
        });

    };
```

I am having and error of **"Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined"**

Comment: Hi where do you call initialize() ?

Comment: I call it on the html part. ng-init="initialize()"

Comment: where do you bind the event scroll?

Comment: inside initialize function. $('#sent').mCustomScrollbar()

Comment: Are you sure your callback are running? i try your code nothing happen

Comment: when I try to bind mCustomScrollbar to the element it gives me this error "Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined.

Comment: you need to add the callback on the directive why did you left? i was writing something based on your directive because your controller isn't running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156400/discussion-between-headmax-and-rafraf-dela-cruz).

Comment: chat is blocked in my workspace. do you have a slack? maybe we can do the conversation there.

Comment: @sorry dunno have slack :(

Comment: i give you an example base to an api ipsum data loader by range, isn't the best but is running using controller and directive. https://codepen.io/headmax/pen/LzrpyP

Answer (score 1):

```
app.directive("whenScrolled", function(){
   return{

      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

     // we get a list of elements of size 1 and need the first element
     raw = elem[0];

     // we load more elements when scrolled past a limit
     elem.bind("scroll", function(){
       if(raw.scrollTop+raw.offsetHeight+5 >= raw.scrollHeight){
         scope.loading = true;

       // we can give any function which loads more elements into the list
         scope.$apply(attrs.whenScrolled);
       }
     });
   }
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/headmax/pen/LzrpyP

Comment: That was my first code and it is running smoothly.
But I am no longer using the directive because i want to do it with mCustomScrollbar onTotalScroll callbacks.

Comment: ok i didn't known i just forked but i got 3 others if you need ;).